# Symfony2 - Security authentication

Tags: php, symfony

```
- { path: ^/event, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```

In my *security.yml*, I would like to authenticate all `/xxx` except `/` and `/event`, is there a way to do so? What I did above will not work. The only way for it to work is to add individual pages everytime i create one.

```
- { path: ^/event, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```

I cannot add `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` on the root in the 3rd line because that would be so wrong.

Comment: It uses regular expressions. You could configure yours to check only for one slash, instead of "begins with slash"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this in your access_control:

```
- { path: ^/event, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```